# Inner circle, How to draw it using tikz cd?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$U\times F$};

\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] (phi) {$\Phi$};
\node[below= 1cm of phi] (A) {$U$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A.north west) node [midway,below] {$\pi$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A.north east) node [midway,right] {$\pi_1$};
\draw [<-] ([yshift=2mm]A.north) arc[start angle=-90,delta angle=270,radius=0.25cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: please edit your code so that it's compilable wthout guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would have been nice if you mentioned that you have `tikz-cd` code for the diagram from a previous question.

`tikz-cd` makes a `matrix of nodes` that the elements are placed in. By adding `every matrix/.append style={name=M}` you can use `M-m-n` to refer to a specific cell, where `m` is row number and `n` is column number (or vice versa, I can never remember). Then you can use `execute at end picture` to draw the arrow relative to the bottom middle cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=m},
  execute at end picture={
        \draw [<-] ([yshift=2mm]m-2-2.north) arc[start angle=-90,delta angle=270,radius=0.25cm];
  }]
   E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ]& & U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
      &  U &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```